# vuejs 2 : npm ERR! Could not install from "@/config" as

Tags: npm, vuejs2

I have :

```
$ nodejs --version 
v8.9.4
$ npm --version    
5.6.0
```

I try to join that  https://github.com/wxs77577/adminify vuejs/vuetify template with latest laravel.
I do as next:
1) laravel new Songs

2) cd Songs

```
 php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.6.8
```

3) I copied all files from adminify/src/ into /resources/assets/js/ in Songs project folder

4) I modified my webpack.mix.js as :

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/main.js', 'public/js')    // main.js is entry point of the project 
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

5)  Into my resources/assets/js/http.js I added axios headers configuration from Laravel's resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js, so it has content :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import config from './config'

// enable mock
// import mock from './mock'
// if (!config.debug.mock) {
//   mock.restore()
// }


window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}


var http = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.api,
  timeout: 1000
  // headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') }
})
http.interceptors.request.use(function (request) {
  return request
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
http.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  const request = response.config
  if (config.debug.http) {
    console.log(
      '>>>', request.method.toUpperCase(), request.url, request.params,
      '\n   ', response.status, response.data
    )
  }
  return response
}, function (error) {
  if (config.debug.http) {
    let { response, config: request } = error
    if (request) {
      console.log(
        '>>>', request.method.toUpperCase(), request.url, request.params,
        '\n   ', response.status, response.data
      )
    }
  }
  // Do something with response error
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
Vue.prototype.$http = http
```

6) In package.json I added dependencies from adminify/package.json, so now my /package.json has content :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "adonis-websocket-client": "^1.0.2",
        "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "i": "^0.3.5",
        "indicative": "^2.2.1",
        "vue": "^2.3.3",
        "vue-i18n": "^6.1.1",
        "vue-quill-editor": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-router": "^2.3.1",
        "vue-timeago": "^3.3.1",
        "vue2-dropzone": "^2.0.0"
    },

    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"

        "Validator": "^1.0.4",
        "autoprefixer": "^6.7.2",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.8.1",
        "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
        "chalk": "^1.1.3",
        "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
        "eslint": "^3.19.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
        "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^2.0.7",
        "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-html": "^2.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
        "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
        "express": "^4.14.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
        "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
        "indicative": "^2.2.1",
        "mockjs": "^1.0.1-beta3",
        "opn": "^4.0.2",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
        "ora": "^1.2.0",
        "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
        "semver": "^5.3.0",
        "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "stylus": "^0.54.5",
        "stylus-loader": "^2.1.1",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
        "vue-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.3",
        "vuetify": "^0.14",
        "vuex": "^2.3.1",
        "webpack": "^2.6.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
    }

}
```

7) After that I run

```
$ npm install
npm WARN The package vue is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package indicative is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

8) and last :

```
$ npm run watch-poll   

> @ watch-poll /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs
> npm run watch -- --watch-poll


> @ watch /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch-poll"

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active                                         
Webpack is watching the files…

 78% advanced chunk optimization/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:188
            chunk.sortModules();
                  ^

TypeError: chunk.sortModules is not a function
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:188:19
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3096:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1055:9)
    at eachOf (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1103:5)
    at Object.eachLimit (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3158:5)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:184:27)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at Compilation.seal (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:579:8)
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:493:16
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:289:11
    at _addModuleChain (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:481:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:452:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch-poll"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-03-07T12_24_13_366Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch-poll script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-03-07T12_24_13_388Z-debug.log
```

Content of 018-03-07T12_33_56_015Z-debug.log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'development' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'predevelopment', 'development', 'postdevelopment' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predevelopment: @
6 info lifecycle @~development: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~development: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~development: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs/node_modules/.bin:/home/serge/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/serge/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~development: CWD: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs
10 silly lifecycle @~development: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~development: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~development: Failed to exec development script
13 verbose stack Error: @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Songs
16 verbose Linux 4.13.0-36-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development"
18 verbose node v8.9.4
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ development script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Show `./resources/assets/js/i18n/index.js` and `./resources/assets/js/main.js`.

Comment: I show 2 requested files in original post

Comment: Do you have a `config.js` or `config/index.js` and a `styles/main.styl` in your project? At the root (or `src`) folder? Maybe these files are somewhere else?

Comment: I added 2 file you mentioned to the original post. Could you please give a hint what I have to search for ?

Comment: You have a problem with your webpack configuration. Can you post it as well? look for a file named `webpack.something.js` or other files with `config.something.js` or `something.env.js` in their names.

Comment: I attached content of 2 more files

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I recreate the project from the start with updated npm and nodejs.
I replaced the original post with steps I did.
Could you, please, to take a look?

Comment: Check the comments @ answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your webpack configuration. A couple of options:

## Fix the imports

- In **`./resources/assets/js/i18n/index.js`**:

  Replace:

  ```
  import config from '@/config'
  ```

  with:

  ```
  import config from '../config'
  ```
- And in **`/resources/assets/js/main.js`**:

  Replace:

  ```
  import '@/styles/main.styl'
  ```

  with:

  ```
  import './styles/main.styl'
  ```

Try the above. If it doesn't work, **undo it** and try the one below.

## Alternative: Changing webpack config

If you are going to try this option, undo the suggested changes above.

To update your webpack config, in your **`webpack.mix.js`**, which is like:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/main.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Add a `mix.webpackConfig({`, making it like:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve:{
        /* Path Shortcuts */
        alias:{
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/js')
        }
    }
})

mix.js('resources/assets/js/main.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Try: `npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2`

Comment: I recreated the project 1 more time, but I had the same error pointing at chunk.sortModules();
I followed your instructions as for configurations changes and running npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 command, but the same error
1) I zipped the project. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbfsbajibp06uhc/Songs.zip?dl=0
If you have time/possibility could you please to look at it?

2) Could you advice some laravel5.5/5.6 / vuejs2.5 vuetify backend startup ?
responsive design(boostrap would be good).
Thanks!

Comment: I did `npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 webpack@3` and it got past that error of yours.

Comment: Check it out now, there are compile errors, but maybe you know how to handle them, since they have to do with sass/scss.

Comment: Abous the suggestions, I don't really know any Laravel, sorry I can suggest you any better. I know vue/javascript well and a bit of webpack.

Comment: Oh, I noticed you are a new user, just FIY: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205 if the answer helped, of course.